# Use NSNumberFormatter with multiple NSTextFields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

I have several text fields bound to each other that continuously update based on the value in top text field (see application screenshot below). I'm trying to use NSNumberFormatter to format the values in each text field based on the length of the string in the text field. If the string is too long then I want the formatter style to switch to `Scientific`. I am using an `IBAction` to `alloc init` the number formatter.

I know there is `-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj` but this only works for the active NSTextField; I need the other text fields to also be formatted as their values change.

How do I accomplish this without having to set an IBOutlet for each text field?

My formatter class:

```
#import "FormatterObject.h"

@interface FormatterObject ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;

@property double numA, numB, numC;

@end

@implementation FormatterObject

- (IBAction)chooseFormatter:(id)sender {

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [formatter setThousandSeparator:@","];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:6];

    if ( [[_textField stringValue] length] < 10) {
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        [_textField setFormatter:formatter];
    }

    else {
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
        [_textField setFormatter:formatter];    
    }

    formatter = nil;
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumB {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"numA"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingNumC {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"numA"];
}

- (void)setNumB:(double)theNumB {
    [self setNumA:theNumB * 1000];
}

- (double)numB {
    return [self numA] / 1000;
}

- (void)setNumC:(double)theNumC {
    [self setNumA:theNumC * 1000000];
}

- (double)numC {
    return [self numA] / 1000000;
}

- (void)setNilValueForKey:(NSString*)key {
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"numA"]) return [self setNumA: 0];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"numB"]) return [self setNumB: 0];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"numC"]) return [self setNumC: 0];
    [super setNilValueForKey:key];
}

@end
```

Here's what my application looks like:

[image]

And here are the bindings for each text field:

[image]

Comment: Hello Gavin, you might check out `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`.